# Puppeteer Ubereats.com form input doesn't work

Tags: node.js, forms, web-scraping, google-cloud-functions, puppeteer

I am trying to automize ordering food on UberEats with puppeteer and Google Cloud Functions. However filling in the form location and clicking next won't work. I am currently using Node.js 8 and puppeteer version 2.1.1.

```js
exports.main = (req, res) => {

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let selector = 'button[class="c1 cg ch ci bb bc bd cj ch az ao aq bu aj c1 ck cl cm cn co"]';

async function run () {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({args: ['--no-sandbox']});
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto("https://ubereats.com/nl");
        await page.waitFor('input[id="location-typeahead-home-input"]');
        await page.evaluate(() => {
            document.querySelector('input[id="location-typeahead-home-input"]').value = "Leuven";
            document.querySelector('selector').click();
        });
        await page.waitForSelector('div[class="f5 bc bd be ew bf b1 he"]');
        let element = await page.evaluate(() => {
            return document.querySelector('h2').innerText;
        })
        browser.close();
        return element;
    } catch (e) {
        return e;
    }
}

run()
.then(el => {
  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.status(200).send(el);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send("An Error occured" + err);  
  })

};
```

Webscraping the webpage works fine. Running this code returns no Error only an empty object.

Comment: did you try using their api?

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out a way, although very hacky, how to do this. I suppose it has something to do with React being sluggish. Anyways, here's the code:

```js
import { launch } from 'puppeteer';

main();

async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await launch({
      headless: false,
    });
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    await page.setUserAgent(
      'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0'
    );
    await page.goto('https://www.ubereats.com/nl');

    const inputSelector = '#location-typeahead-home-input';

    await page.waitForSelector(inputSelector);

    await page.waitFor(3000);

    await page.type(inputSelector, 'Leuven');

    await page.waitFor(3000);

    await page.click('button.c1');

    // rest of the code
  } catch (err) {
    // error handling
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the solution but not for google cloud functions. But I think that GCF will not be able to do this function since it will not set a UserAgent. I see that you set headless to false, this can meen that the UberEats site "could be looking for the Headless added to the UA string and blocking that. Or they could be using some techniques to detect automated access and prevent it." But thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I have came up with a solution. As far as why the button isn't being pressed, I have no idea. But, what does work is entering an address and then clicking the first address suggestion.

Here is my code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
async function start(){
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto("https://www.ubereats.com/ca")
    await page.type("#location-typeahead-home-input", "Address")
    await page.waitForSelector('#location-typeahead-home-item-0');
    await page.click("#location-typeahead-home-item-0")
    await page.waitForNavigation()

    console.log(page.url())
    await browser.close()
}

start()
```